# Translating relational algebra expression to SQL?

Tags: sql, algebra, relational

Total rookie taking my first database class here and could use some help writing the SQL equivalent of this relational algebra expression. I can find resources on how to translate the algebra to SQL, but not many on translating the other way around. Thanks in advance!

π{studentId, name} σtitle=‘Information Systems’ (Student ∞ Attends ∞ Course)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT S.studentId, S.name
FROM Student S, Attends A, Course C
WHERE title="Information Systems"
AND S.key1=A.key1
AND A.key2=C.key2
```

Where Key1 is the attribute that relates Student with Attends and Key2 the one that relates Attends with Course.

If you could post the tables structure it would be easier to answer the question. I don't know if the syntax is completely correct, I wrote SQL code for the last time some months ago.